# pointers in objective-c, how do i call the function in the right way - beginners question

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, function-pointers

i have a dynamically made prototype:

```
typedef double ICEDouble;
-(BOOL) getPosition:(SyDRpcInterfacePositionType)type longitude:(ICEDouble *)longitude latitude:(ICEDouble *)latitude;
```

and i would call it so, because i have no plan, how to do it in the right way:

```
NSNumber* longitudeReturn;
NSNumber** latitudeReturn;      
[prx getPosition:SyDRpcInterfaceMAPMATCHED longitude:longitudeReturn latitude:latitudeReturn];
```

the compiler says:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'getPosition:longitude:latitude:' from incompatible pointer type  
warning: passing argument 3 of 'getPosition:longitude:latitude:' from incompatible pointer type
```

not really surprising, but can anyone please tell me how to do it right ?
maybe with a little explanation for a beginner ?

Comment: You should also add how `ICEDouble` is defined. Is it a typedef to a `double`, or is it an Objective-C class?

Comment: typedef double ICEDouble;  

yes, it is double, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ICEDouble` is typedef'd to `double', it looks like the method you are calling has two 'out' parameters. It should be called like this:

```
double lat, long;
[prx getPosition:SyDRpcInterfaceMAPMATCHED longitude:&long latitude:&lat];
```

This is a common idiom when a method needs to return multiple values, without object overhead. If needed, you can then convert these to `NSNumber`s if you need them, via:

```
NSNumber * nLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat];
NSNumber * nLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:long];
```

Check the return type of `getPosition:` though. If it returns a `BOOL` you will want to check the result before using the returned values. Otherwise, `lat` and `long` will represent garbage values.

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

1. The signature defines `ICEDouble`, you provide `NSNumber`.
2. With `NSNumber** latitudeReturn`, you define a pointer to a pointer.

So I guess it should be

```
ICEDouble* longitudeReturn;
ICEDouble* latitudeReturn;      
[prx getPosition:SyDRpcInterfaceMAPMATCHED longitude:longitudeReturn latitude:latitudeReturn];
```

Answer (score 0):

and on this construct ?

```
    SyDRpcInterfaceNavInfos** datenSammlung;



    //-(BOOL) getGuidanceInfos:(SyDRpcInterfaceNavInfos **)infos;

    if([prx getGuidanceInfos:&datenSammlung]) {//further activities}
```

wether if i let the &, nor if i leave the end because of the extra pointer-*, the programm quits with both constellations at here. the SyDRpcInterfaceNavInfos is a struct.